# Network Operating System

Tags: operating-system

From where can I get the comparison among different Network Operating Systems(NOSs)?
I mean can anyone provide me any useful link for the same?

Can Windows 2000 and later be considered as NOSs? I read at wikipedia that they just support networking, that's it, they cannot be considered as NOSs or can they?

Comment: What is your definition of NOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an obsolete term, no one uses it in the context you're asking about any more.  I would say that it's been obsolete since the early 90's: somewhere around that time, networking features became a required part of any OS.

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time the NOS was distinct from the OS, mainly because networking was added long after computers already had operating systems. As such it was an add-on to the OS. Even as recently as the 80's most computers were sold with no networking capabilities as standard. These days the OS and NOS are intertwined to the point that they are, for all practical purposes, one and the same. So, as Ward pointed out, it's an obsolete term in today's context.